# How to create multi-request based on last json response in JMeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

I will get json response from last request, then I will parse the response and get a variable array, then create new request base on each element in that array one by one. I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: please share the JSON response (at least the array part that needs to be captured).

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) combination. The idea is to have variables like:

```
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
var_3=baz
```

So you would be able to iterate them using [foreach loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop). See [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) article to get the overall idea.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow:

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) (>= 3.0 version) Or [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (< 3.0 version) plugin, to the HTTP Request sampler, as a child, in which JSON response is received.
2. Add the `JSON Path Expressions` to capture the specific values and store it in variable names, say `capturedArray`. refer [JSON Path Syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).
3. In later requests, i.e., HTTP Request Samplers, you can retrieve the array value by using the syntax `${capturedArray}`

Comment: thanks, I know how to get one variable from json, but how to create the array and read each element from it, it there a specific example?

Comment: Is the value you retrieved in JSON is an array? Or You want to capture different responses from JSON and combine it to an array? please add these details to the question to get the specific answer. Otherwise, we will be in an infinite loop :)

Comment: I got response like this: [{"token":"jkn34lk", "content":"111"},{"token":"er34334", "content":"123"}...], I want to extract all token value from the array above, and then create requests like this: http://129.214.45.22?token=jkn34lk; http://129.214.45.22?token=er34334